# col-xs-9 taking 9 columns on desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I started learning bootstrap from [GetBootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping) source and I saw an example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-9">.col-xs-9</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">.col-xs-4<br>Since 9 + 4 = 13 &gt; 12, this 4-column-wide div gets wrapped onto a new line as one contiguous unit.</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6<br>Subsequent columns continue along the new line.</div>
</div>
```

Now `col-xs-9` means they should take 9 columns on mobile. It is also taking 9 columns on my desktop screen. How is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:  Grid System in framework is `12 column` layout.**

Yes it's functioning properly as expected because whenever you apply a class.

Let suppose `xs` then it the same property will be applied to `xs` and screen greater than of that size.

So in your case `col-xs-9` will be applied to `extra-small` screen and screen having resolution greater than that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to take 100% of the width on desktop, try `<div class="col-xs-9 col-md-12">`.

Each column equals 1/12th of 100% width. Therefore if you want to get 100%, then the column sum needs to equal 12.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

This example would make 3 DIVs below each other on mobile(12 = 100% width) but 3 DIVs per 100% width on desktops(4x3 = 100% width). This example is more often used in practice when you want DIVs to take up more width on smaller screens.

See [this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) for a more detailed explanation. Also, I found [this tutorial](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works) really helpful when I first started out trying to understand the grid system.

Answer (score -2):

You can add different classes based on your Device `width`.

In Bootstrap grid system, it is scaled to a maximum of 12 columns. In the above example 9+4+6=18.

Sum should always be `equal or less than 12`.

**Example**

`<div class="col-xs-9 col-md-5">` will take up 9 columns in mobile and 5 columns in desktop.

**For Different devices :**

- `col-xs-*`(for mobiles)
- `col-sm-*`(for small devices)
- `col-md-*`(for desktops)
- `col-lg-*`(for larger devices)